# Set $PATH as OpenLDAP attribute

Tags: centos, users, path, openldap

I need to set `$PATH` for OpenLDAP users (CentOS6/7). Not in `.profile`, not in `.bashrc` on client machine, but as attribute in LDAP on the LDAP server so it is set whenever the user logs onto any host via `ssh`. Nothing on client side -- LDAP server only. Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: this will require code on the client that gets some attribute from LDAP and sticks it into the environment list, somehow

Answer (score 1):

An LDAP directory only *stores* data, you need the LDAP client layer (e.g. `pam_ldap`) to *do* things with it. Unlike NetWare/ActiveDirectory, having a login script in the directory as a user property isn't a standard thing in other environments, and there is no standard attribute to store [a path to] such a script (though `labelledURI` is a candidate).

With PAM+NSS, only a handful of "databases" which you can point to LDAP are supported (passwd, groups, etc see [`nsswitch.conf(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf)) none of which might make this easier.

Neither [PADL `pam_ldap`](https://www.padl.com/pam_ldap.html) nor [`nss-pam-ldap`](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/) offer any flexible kind of LDAP attribute processing beyond filling out the basic [`getpwent()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) `password` structure fields.

But, there are perhaps a couple of workarounds, though none can meet your "nothing on client side" requirement.

1. Use `pam_exec` or `pam_script`, as these are run as child processes of login they cannot effect environment changes directly, but you could script something that made sure that the correct `PATH` always appeared within or at the end of `.profile` (depending on robustness requirements)
2. Use `/etc/profile` to fetch user attributes from LDAP, then set `PATH` accordingly (though you may find it tricky to prevent `.profile` overwriting it)
3. Modify `pam_unix` to allow and support misuse of the `loginShell` attribute prefixed with variables, like `PATH=/opt/thing/bin /bin/bash` (will not work with PADL, AFAICT)
4. Modify `pam_umask`, the Linux PAM `pam_umask` already [processes extra information](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_umask) from the gecos field like "umask=nnnn,ulimit=nnnn" so there's some precedent here.
5. Modify `pam_ldap` to save LDAP attributes as PAM "data" via [`pam_set_data()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_set_data), then use `pam_get_data()` in another PAM module to process them (I did this a long time ago, in my case it was to create users on-demand in an SQL user database using details from their LDAP attributes). `pam_env` is a good candidate here.
6. There's a similar concept for PAM "items" ([`pam_set_item()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_set_item)/`pam_get_item()`) for a small set of data items (the previous PAM data concept is for arbitrary name/value data), [`pam_env` supports](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_env.conf) a syntax of `@{PAM_itemname}` to set environment values using these - you *might* be able to misuse an item like `PAM_XDISPLAY`. `pam_ldap` already sets a handful of items, so this is likely the simplest code change.

(To be clear, by "modify" I mean "change the source", so those solutions entail both configuration and binary deployments on clients.)

Here's a (robust-ish) bash example that could be made to work with the first two options:

```
 while read line; do
     [[ "$line" =~ ^description:\ setenv\ ([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)=(.*) ]] && {
         export "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
     }
 done < <(ldapsearch -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -H ldap://ldap0/ -b ${LDAPBASE} \
    -s sub "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=${USER}))" description
```

given one or more "description" attributes per-user of the form:

```
setenv MYVAR=MYVALUE
```

Here we're engaging in the dubious practise of stuffing non-description data into the "description" attribute, a handy way to store up to 1024 characters in a multi-valued attribute. This is a simple approach, using `ldapsearch` you will likely run into trouble if/when values/types cause base64 encoding output.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, mr.spuratic. I will try them tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, althrough not the way I wanted. 
Used puppet to populate .profile files containing export PATH=$PATH:/xxxxxxxx directive.
Combined with removal of ldap entry "shell=\bin\bash" it enabled correct setting of PATH variable.

Thank you for your extensive answer mr spuratic, it was a pleasure to delve into the matter.